# Removing default high-level parts from metric's name in graphite

Tags: logstash, graphite

I use logstash to analyse events and then redirect information to statsd, which moves it to graphite. So when I send metric like **github.users**, it appears in graphite ui like **stats.logstash.host.github.users**.
Is it possible to remove stats.logstash.host prefix?

Comment: Maybe you could use the https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.12/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasSub function to replace the common base name with an empty string.

Comment: @cmur2, This is about displaying in reports which we can query from graphite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to replace "logstash" part via "namespace" option in statsd output for logstash, cause it is default namespace.